# How can I restrict a custom WordPress role access to only a specific plugin?

Tags: admin-menu, user-access, content-restriction

I created a custom plugin . I want to  add some admin side users to use that plugin.

I created a specific role .  But i  want to restrict the those users/role access only that plugin not the entire word press admin.

But how can i restrict the access of that  role ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [User Admin Simplifier](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-admin-simplifier/) plugin. It allows you to hide plugins and options from choosen users.

Comment: have you tried that? if you type the back end url directly ... will  it restrict access ? or just hiding the menu

Comment: I've tried that just now and sadly it doesn't work. I've never tested if this plugin restricts access or just hide plugin - it hides it.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Please add a solution.